# FingerPrint Scanner in Windows tab

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, fingerprint

I want to use Secugen Biometric in windows tab application.
I want to read the user finger print from my application but I am not able to do so

finger print working fine for the default windows sign in, I did much R & D 
Please help me to find resolution

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38881/Fingerprint-Reader-Integration-using-the-M-SYS-SDK

it is also not working